# ffmpeg minterpolate and rubberband - how to stretch audio to fit?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

What is the best way to control the length of the audio and pitch shift using rubberband?

I tried setting `asetpts=PTS*16` to match the video PTS, but it appears to be ignored. The only thing that seems to determine the length of the audio is rubberband pitch. Even `tempo=0.0625` does not appear to do anything.

I would like to be able to set the audio length to match the slower video section and set the pitch to whatever I want, like minimum `0.15` and have it stretch the audio length as needed.  When the pitch gets below around `0.08` it is just low bass or subsonic frequencies.

```
ffmpeg -ss 123.978571 -i "original-120fps.MP4" -filter_complex "
[0:v]trim=0:0.375,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,minterpolate='fps=480',setpts=PTS*16[slowv]; 
[0:a]atrim=0:0.375,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,rubberband=pitch=0.08:tempo=0.0625[slowa];"
 -y -r 60 -map [slowv] -map [slowa] -preset veryfast "output.mp4"
```

Finally, is there a good guide to using lib-rubberband? FFmpeg docs for rubberband list options, but don't explain what they do.